# bash read -r -N skips part of the input

Tags: bash, ubuntu

This line writes "foo", sleeps, and then writes "bla":

```
echo "woo"; sleep 2; echo "bla"
```

I'm trying to read the entire output of this, in two sequential read commands:

```
(echo "woo"; sleep 2; echo "bla") 1> \
>(IFS=""; read -t 0.1 -r -N 10; \
echo "exit code: $? reply: $REPLY"; \
sleep 5; \
read -t 0.1 -r -N 10; \
echo "exit code: $? reply: $REPLY")
```

The first read prints:

> exit code: 142 reply:

which is kinda expected, since 142 is a timeout, and I called read with -t 0.1. But the second read prints:

> exit code: 1 reply: bla

Question: where did "woo" go?!

If I remove the `sleep 2` from the output line, the whole thing works as expected -- reads/outputs the entire "woo\nbla" sequence in the first read, and returns 1 (EOF).

The problem reproduces with any sleep, no matter how short. It also doesn't matter if I use a pipe to redirect output instead of >1. This is Ubuntu.

Edit: I want to read into a buffer of N characters, and read the input as-is, without any word-splitting on delimeters. Hence the -N and IFS="".

Edit: this is a toy example to demonstrate a general problem. What I'm trying to do is to implement a smarter version of tee in bash: it should behave like tee, except it should wait for its input-generating process to stop, then flush its buffers, and exit. The real tee hangs indefinitely if the input-generating process starts some zombie child processes, because they then occupy the stdout handle and it never gets closed. Using tail --pid works, but unfortunately it doesn't work on Windows, and I need this to be multi-platform. I thought this could be accomplished by calling read -t -N in a loop, but apparently that doesn't work...

Answer (score 6):

> Question: where did "woo" go?!

The `woo` was read by the first `read -t 0.1 -r -N 10` and then this command failed, because it did not receive 10 characters or EOF character within the set timeout.

According to the [read man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html):

> ```
>   -N nchars   return only after reading exactly NCHARS characters, unless
>       EOF is encountered or read times out, ignoring any delimiter
>   -t timeout  time out and return failure if a complete line of input is
>       not read withint TIMEOUT seconds.  The value of the TMOUT
>       variable is the default timeout.  TIMEOUT may be a
>       fractional number.  If TIMEOUT is 0, read returns success only
>       if input is available on the specified file descriptor.  The
>       exit status is greater than 128 if the timeout is exceeded
> ```

---

> Edit: I want to read into a buffer of N characters, and read the input
>   as-is, without any word-splitting on delimeters. Hence the -N and
>   IFS="".

If you call `read` command two times, each instance of it has a separate buffer. To solve this use a single `read` command and adjust or remove the timeout option eg:

```
(echo "woo"; sleep 2; echo "bla") 1> \
>(IFS=""; read -r -N 10; \
echo "exit code: $? reply: $REPLY";)
```

And then, if you want to simultaneously view the incoming input, you can add the `tee` command, eg:

```
(echo "woo"; sleep 2; echo "bla") 1> \
>(tee >(IFS=""; read -r -N 10; \
echo "exit code: $? reply: $REPLY";))
```

Comment: Oh, but I want to read into a buffer of N characters! Sorry, I should have specified that -- this is a part of my attempted implementation of a variation of tee. I want to ignore all the delimeters, and read the input as-is into a fixed buffer in a loop, until a specified source command finishes. Here, I just have the two first calls, because they already produce an unexpected result. "woo" was output first, so it should have been read by one of the calls before "bla", but the output only contains "bla".

Comment: Thank you! 
re: "woo" was consumed by the first read:
From http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read: "If timeout arrives before data is read completely (before end-of-line), the partial data is saved."
So why was the first $REPLY empty? It doesn't seem like a good idea to drop the partial output buffer on timeouts -- how can we then reconstruct the full input with buffered reads.

Comment: @OlaRozenfeld The `read` command probably intentionally does not set the reply variable when it fails. However, it seems to be undocumented.

Comment: A single read command will not suffice to read the entire input, since input is generated by the process running concurrently with the read. We have to call read in a loop to get all the input. And we must provide a timeout to each read, since without it, read would hang indefinitely if the output process starts a zombie (try inserting a `sleep 60&` between echos). That's why I'm basically trying to reimplement a smarter version of tee myself using read and echo in a loop. If read really swallows parts of the input without any indication on timeouts, that's just screwed up...

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce a `sleep` right before reading the output from stdout. This `sleep` should be at least the same or larger amount that the input.

```
 (echo "woo"; sleep 1; echo "blah") 1> >( IFS=""; \
   sleep 1; read -t 0.1 -N 10; echo $REPLY; sleep 2; \
   read -t 0.1 -N 10; echo $REPLY)
```

In your case `echo woo` gets gobbled up by the following sleep command. By the time `output` redirection happens, all it sees `sleep 1; echo "blah"`.

And you have another problem. You are trying to read `10` characters with `-N` option, where as you are providing is `3`, causing it to exit with code `142`. Try with `-N 4`.

Following will exit with `code = 0`;

```
  $ (echo "woo"; sleep 1; echo "blah") 1> >( IFS=""; \
    sleep 1; read -t 0.1 -N 4; echo "code: $?"; \ 
    echo $REPLY; sleep 2; read -t 0.1 -N 4; echo "code: $?"; \
    echo $REPLY)

  code: 0
  woo
  code: 0
  blah
```

Comment: Right, but I was looking for an explanation of what happened there, in order to understand how to solve it on a non-toy example. How could the first part of the input be skipped by a process which reads from a redirected input? Something needed to consume these "woo" characters. Stdout is supposed to be sequential.Adding a sleep to the reader process won't be a generic solution, I'm afraid, as the scheduling is non-deterministic.

Comment: See my updated answer. Your issue seems to be the number of characters you are trying to read vs the the number of characters you are providing as input

Comment: Thank you! Re: By the time output redirection happens, all it sees `sleep 1; echo "blah"`: isn't output redirection supposed to catch the entire output by definition? If we redirect the output to cat instead, both things get printed.
Re: reading 3 characters into a buffer of 10 characters: that's exactly what I'm trying to do -- implement sequential buffered reads. In general, I have a process P1, which writes various stuff to stdout, at unknown rate. I want to read that output in process P2 up to N characters at a time, or however many are currently available, and process them, in a loop.